# How do I prevent a process from running twice if 2 different users run it at the same time in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, duplicates

I have a front-end form that fetches data from a back-end table. The front-end has multiple users and they use the back-end table simultaneously. The user uses a form to generate reports. Let's say if a user click the "view" button, the background process will insert data to a table and it will show the result.

However, my problem is if 2 different users from different locations click the "view" button from their end machine at the same time, the process on the back-end table runs twice and it duplicates the data.

I know we can delete duplicate data from the table itself but what I'm trying to do is if there's a way to stop one process if there's already a same process running.

I have found a scenario similar to my problem but it is only caused by clicking the button twice.

[Here's the link for the similar problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274458/vba-eventhandler-firing-twice)

I hope someone could help me out. It's my firs time to use VBA and I have no previous knowledge/experience with it.

Comment: This is likely an XY problem, you don't actually want to store automatically generated results in a table on the backend. Reliably locking and unlocking an action between multiple computers without a real server is a pain, there's no simple solution if you want to proceed that way.

Comment: Does the table being updated hold just the data for that specific report?  You could move the table to the front-end so each user has their own copy.

Comment: The table is needed for other reports and it was put in the backend so as to give real time updates for different users. Initially, the table was in the front end but when a user update/insert a new data to the table, it is not reflected real time to the other users hence we put it in the back end.

Comment: Need code to check if record already exists and if it does, not to save another. Or set field(s) with index, probably compound, to not allow duplicate value. Exactly what data is input to this table and why?

Comment: You have a simple choice here. You generate the data to a temp table (in the front end), and thus your issue goes away. Your problem is that you have to run a report, and generate "some" data when you launch that report, but ALSO use some existing data in that temp table. This design simply will not work in a mutli-user environment. It too difficult to split up data that you generate into that temp table + additional existing data that supposed to be in that table. I mean, what happens if the same user runs the report again - how to you determine if existing ID's are already in that table?

Comment: Thank you, June7. Setting a compound index solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to prevent a process for running twice but we were able to find a workaround for my concern by assigning a compound index to the table. It no longer accepts duplicates regardless of the process running multiple times simultaneously.